# how does curl works for file upload

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl code which download file from remote host which is working fine.What I need to do is to make sure the file is downloaded completely and then run the next lines But I'm not sure what Curl does.I want to be sure that other line of code will not be executed while CURL is downloading the file from remote server.
This is the code

```
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_FILE => $fh,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
        CURLOPT_URL => $target_zip.'.zip',
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curl object` while be close after curl done, which means your `$ch` will be executed and be closed after the work is done (`curl_close($ch);`), and then the script will move on and execute next line of php script, this is what happened when you are writing simple PHP script.
If you are talking about throwing curl work to background and doing some other job meantime, while the curl is finish and some specific line of script (maybe a function) will be called, I think you are looking for Ajax, in that case I think `callback` is what you need.

Comment: So ,My code is waiting for upload to be completed and then move on to the next lines?The problem is this.It's a zip file curl is downloading and Right after  curl_close($ch);  The script begins to open the zip file to extract.But it returns failed to open zip file .So i guess the download is in progress when It tries to open it.

Comment: .$zip->open return error 19 which is nozip.I guess the download is in process when the script tries to open zip file.How should I make sure curl would wait until the download is complete and then execute next line of php script?

Comment: Not very sure the whole situation you have met, maybe you could paste more code here (include uploading part), then we can help more.
On the other hand, did you close ```fh``` after the work is done ?

Comment: Thanks I have forgotten to close fh.